# How to compare elements in an array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I will give you an example of what I want to do. If we have as input:

```
 1 4 3 2
```

I want to print *all the numbers* which are *bigger* than all the elements to *their right*. Here we have to print **4, 3** and **2**. I've converted the input to an array, but I don't know how to compare the elements.

```
 int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine()
            .Split()
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: What about using two `for` cycles?

Comment: Iterate through the array backwards and track the maximum value you've seen so far.  As you encounter each value, check if it's greater that the maximum so far, and if so store it.  Output the stored numbers in reverse order.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the current element is maximum of right slice of array :

```
int[] numbers = new int[]{ 1, 4 ,3 ,2 };
var result=numbers.Where((number, i) => number == numbers.Skip(i).Max()).ToList();
```

Output:

```
4,3,2
```

Comment: works if you have distinct values in array otherwise you need to use the All method

Comment: How do you use All() here?

Comment: int[] numbers = new int[] { 1, 4, 3, 2 };
            var result = numbers.Where((number, i) =>   numbers.Skip(i+1).All(x=>x<number)).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using LINQ, like this:

```cs
var numbers = new[] { 1, 4, 3, 2 };
var query =
    from info in numbers.Select((n, i) => (n, i))
    where numbers.Skip(info.i + 1).All(value => info.n > value)
    select info.n;
```

The way this works is:

````cs
// Iterate over the numbers, keeping track of the index of each one
from info in numbers.Select((n, i) => (n, i))

// For each item, make sure it's greater than the ones on its right
where numbers.Skip(info.i + 1).All(value => info.n > value)

// If that's the case, select that item
select info.n;
```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine()
            .Split()
            .Select(int.Parse)
            .ToArray();
        string[] topIntegers = new string[numbers.Length];
        int maximumValue = int.MinValue;
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = numbers.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (numbers[i] > maximumValue)
            {
                maximumValue = numbers[i];
                topIntegers[j] = maximumValue.ToString();
            }
            j++;
        }

        for (int i = topIntegers.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Console.Write($"{topIntegers[i]} ");
        }
```

I made it in this way but I got incorrect results on this test:

```
 14 24 3 19 15 17
```

My output is:

```
 24  19  17
```

but expected is:

```
 24 19 17
```

Comment: is not it same?

Comment: No, see the intervals.

Comment: Don't mean to interrupt, but have you looked at my answer?
It does what you're asking for with just 3 lines of code, this code here is way too complicated for what you need.
I've added a line by line explanation, but feel free to ask if anything's not clear for you.

Comment: @Sergio0694,  thank you, but I didn't use it because I haven't learned LINQ and I don't understand it at all. I should solve it using arrays. :)

Comment: @NikolDimitrova: Your problem is that you are doing your console.write for the empty entries in the array too. This is then printing an extra space for each empty element in your topIntegers array. As a thought have you considered just adding them to a `List<int>`? That way you'll only have the numbers you want without the spacing that your current method is giving you.

Comment: j++ should be inside of if block

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Aggregate:

```
int[] allNumbers = new int[] { 1, 4, 3, 2 };
int[] filteredNumbers = allNumbers.Aggregate(new List<int>(), (result, x) => {
    var filteredResult = new List<int>(result.Where(y => y > x));
    filteredResult.Add(x);
    return filteredResult;
}).ToArray();
```